# Using kqueue to poll for exceptional conditions

Tags: sockets, kqueue

I'm modifying an app in order to replace its use of select() with kqueue. select() allows one to poll for exceptional conditions:

```
int select(int nfds,
     fd_set *restrict readfds,
     fd_set *restrict writefds,
     fd_set *restrict errorfds,           <---- this thing here
     struct timeval *restrict timeout
);
```

After reading the kqueue documentation it looks like there's no way to do that. There's `EVFILT_READ` and `EVFILT_WRITE` but nothing along the lines of `EVFILT_ERROR`/`EVFILT_EXCEPTIONAL`. Is it possible to poll for exceptional conditions, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as exceptional state on FreeBSD, to quote `man 2 select`:

> The only exceptional condition detectable is out-of-band data received on a socket.

So your question boils down to “How can I detect OOB-data on a socket with kqueue”, which I, to be honest, cannot answer without doing some research.